# How do I prevent fetching data multiple times inside a Repository?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My `EloquentUserRepository` (concrete implementation) has some methods like `getCompanies($userId)` and `getProfile($userId)`, for example.

In both cases, before returning stuff, they fetch the user, like so:

```
$user = User::find($userId);
```

So, when I need to call those two methods in the same request, the data is fetched twice.

Am I missing something or am I using repositories wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

What if you approached it from the relationship side instead? I'm assuming that `Companies` live in a different table. So could you acquire the companies with something like this?

```
<?php 

class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'avatar'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Company', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Then you could find the companies with:

```
$user = User::find($userId)->load('companies')->get();
```

and you'd already have the companies loaded.

If the profile is in a different table you could do a similar relationship, like this:

```
<?php

class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'avatar'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function profile()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I'm not certain if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it's the approach I like to use when finding items that are related to a particular model.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you misinterpreted my question. I'm using the Repository design pattern and I'm looking for the best practice to not have to fetch the User or any other model twice, when I'm calling a repository method.

Comment: As far as I understand the repository pattern, you are abstracting business logic away from your models. So in this example I'm not sure how you could get a User's companies, without first getting the user. I suppose you could load the profile and the company with `$user = User::find($userId)->load('companies', 'profile')->get();`